# JPA OneToMany JoinColumn non primarykey

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, unique-index, joincolumn

I have 2 entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "THINGS")
public class Thing {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "THING_PK")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name= "NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONS")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PERSON_PK")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name= "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name= "GROUP_ID")
    private Long groupId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName = "GROUP_ID")
    private List<Thing> things;
}
```

I am not sure do I correct mapping or not, but generally idea is following:
If "persons" are belong same group than they should have same "things".

The first question: Is this mapping correct ideologically and technically?

if yes:

I create DB dynamically, using annotations. And it creates constraint what I don't expect.

[image]

As result when I carry out this code:

```
List<Thing> thingList = new ArrayList<Thing>();

Person person = new Person();
person.setFirstName("Name1");
person.setGroupId(1L);
person.setThings(thingList);


Thing thing1 = new Thing();
thing1.setName("Name1");
thingList.add(thing1);


Thing thing2 = new Thing();
thing2.setName("Name2");
thingList.add(thing2);
entityManager.persist(person);
List<Thing> thingList2 = new ArrayList<Thing>();

Person person2 = new Person();
person2.setFirstName("Name2");
person2.setGroupId(2L);
person2.setThings(thingList2);


Thing thing3 = new Thing();
thing3.setName("Name3");
thingList2.add(thing3);
entityManager.persist(person2);

Person person3 = new Person();
person3.setFirstName("Name3");
person3.setGroupId(1L);
person3.setThings(thingList);
entityManager.persist(person3);
```

I receive:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:Unique index or primary key violation: "FK_THINGS_GROUP_ID_INDEX_2 ON PUBLIC.PERSONS(GROUP_ID) VALUES (1, 2)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO PERSONS (FIRSTNAME, GROUP_ID) VALUES (?, ?) [23505-188]
Error Code: 23505
Call: INSERT INTO PERSONS (FIRSTNAME, GROUP_ID) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [Name1, 1]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Person{id=null, firstName='Name1', groupId=1, things=[Thing{id=null, name='Name1'}, Thing{id=null, name='Name2'}]})
```

Comment: Is it logical?  Sure though I might make a group class to wrap/represent what this group_id really means to your model.  As for the foreign key, this should be expected as it is what your join column annotation is specifying.  If the group_id field in person is not going to be unique, then the relationship is a M:M not a 1:M and doesn't make sense - it really should be broken up into a group intermediary, so that many persons and many things can belong to the same group.